# How do I change the position of a north arrow in a layout using arcpy.mp?

Tags: python, layout, element, arcpy

I'm trying to change the position of a north arrow using arcpy.mp. My code is below:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\Aliza\Desktop\GIS Programming Fundamentals\Lab9\Lab9Doc\Lab9Doc.aprx")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Georgia*")[0]
NorthArrow = arcpy.mp.listElements(aprx, lyt, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "NorthArrow")
elm = lyt.listElements("GRAPHIC_ELEMENT", "North Arrow")
elm.elementPositionX = 6.4
elm.elementPositionY = 3.6
aprx.save()
del aprx

This is the error I am getting:

    NorthArrow = arcpy.mp.listElements(aprx, lyt, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "NorthArrow")
AttributeError: module 'arcpy.mp' has no attribute 'listElements'
```

Comment: There are many thousands of ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro questions asked and answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable NorthArrow is not defined properly. List functions return a list of objects, use the index 0 (`[0]`) to return the first object of the list:

```
NorthArrow  = lyt.listElements(wildcard="NorthArrow")[0]
```

Make sure the North arrow element name is indeed "NorthArrow" by checking its properties in the layout.

Then move the North arrow and save your project:

```
NorthArrow.elementPositionX = 6.4
NorthArrow.elementPositionY = 3.6
aprx.save()
```